# "Heard from" with various recent-past phrases

Tags: present-perfect, time

Have you heard from John...

a. recently
b. two days ago
c. since two days
d. for two days

What is the best answer?  Since recently and for two days can use in the present perfect tense

Comment: (b) *two days ago* refers to a *specific* time in the past, so we'd ask about that using ***Did you hear** from John two days ago?* (d) *for two days* is not-idiomatic unless negated as ***Have you not** heard from John for two days?* Correspondingly, the respondent might answer *I haven't heard from him for a week*, but he would never say *I [have] heard from him for a week*. Also note that he might say *I [have] heard from him recently* or *...two days ago*, but never *...since two days* without ***ago***.

Answer (score 2):

> a. Have you heard from John recently?

Perfect

> b. Have you heard from John two days ago?

No. It should be "Did you hear from John two days ago?"

> c. Have you heard from John since two days?

It does not sound correct. Rather, "Have you heard from John in the last two days?"
Interestingly, "Have you heard from John since yesterday?", which is almost the same sentence structure, sounds ok.

> d. Have you heard from John for two days?

No. As the commenter mentioned, a negation such as "I have not heard from John for two days" is ok.

Comment: The best answer must be a,isn't it?.So you can't use for + period of time in a question.Don't get me wrong cuz my english is bad

Comment: sure, answer a is fine.  Or as mentioned "Have you heard from John in the last two days?"